# Add key to jsonObject

Tags: android, json, key

I want to make something like this:

> data{"user":{"age":"23","address":"usa"}}

But I kept on constructing this using JsonObject

> {"data":{"user":{"age":"23","address":"usa"}}}

I know that because data is a JsonObject. I just don't know to make it like the one I posted first. Please help

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Post your code so we can help

Comment: the mentioned data is in json format but the data you need is not the json format.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your desired output try this code:

```
    try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("age", "23");
            jsonObject.put("address", "usa");

            JSONObject userJson = new JSONObject();
            userJson.put("user", jsonObject);

            String yourFormat = "data" + userJson.toString();
            Log.d("TAG", "Format: " + yourFormat);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you expected output is not a valid JSON object at all. So libraries like GSON, Jackson, and Logansquare, or even default JSON package in android will not help you.

But since your requirement is something like this I would suggest you simply generate

```
{"user":{"age":"23","address":"usa"}}
```

Using some of the libraries mentioned above and perform some string manipulation. Write a good method to perform this task.